# Python - struggling to print in the following format using dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, printing

I have printed some code which looks like this:

```
print(len(no_of_records))

200
150
2000
```

I have a dictionary list like:

```
list_names = {
    "Yellow_List": "yellow",
    "Blue_List": "blue",
    "Red_List": "red"
}
```

I want to be able to print my key name in my dictionary with the number of records like so:

```
The yellow list has 200
The blue list has 150
The red list has 2000
```

I have tried this

```
for key in list_names:
    print("The", key, "has", len(no_of_records))
```

but i'm getting:

```
The yellow list has 200
The blue list has 200
The red list has 200
The yellow list has 150
The blue list has 150
The red list has 150
The yellow list has 2000
The blue list has 2000
The red list has 2000
```

Comment: what is no_of_records? can you share that code as well?

Comment: Could you provide more of your code, please? It's hard to see what's happening. Do you have each list name three times in the list? Is the for-loop you've posted surrounded by another for-loop? I can't see why len(no_of_records) should change at all inside the loop. It would print 3 times the same number. Which it seems to do, but it does this 3 times again. Which is why I'm asking about a surrounding for-loop.

Comment: Unless you have a for-loop in the `print(len(num_of_records))` this should not print 3 different values. If num_of_records is a list of the same len of `list_names`, then a zip function should be enought. But there is important information missing on your question to make it comprehensible.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
no_records = [200, 150, 2000]
list_names = {
    "Yellow_List": "yellow",
    "Blue_List": "blue",
    "Red_List": "red"
}

for key, x in zip(list_names.values(), no_records):
    print('The', key, 'list has', x)
```

```
The yellow list has 200
The blue list has 150
The red list has 2000
```

Comment: I'd prefer to just combine the output of no_records with the key rather than including it in the code because these numbers can change :)

Comment: You are right, but OP didn't provide the object `no_of_records`.